# New column based on the value of another column | Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

In an Oracle 11g database I have table called `organizations` which looks like this:

```
| ORGANIZATION_ID | ORGANIZATION_NAME | TREE_ORGANIZATION_ID | ORGANIZATION_RANG |
|-----------------|-------------------|----------------------|-------------------|
| 1               | Facebook          | \1                   | 1                 |
| 2               | Instagram         | \1\2                 | 2                 |
| 3               | Whatsapp          | \1\3                 | 2                 |
| 4               | Alphabet          | \4                   | 1                 |
| 5               | Nest              | \4\5                 | 2                 |
| 6               | Google            | \4\6                 | 2                 |
| 7               | YouTube           | \4\6\7               | 3                 |
```

As you can see this table has column called `TREE_ORGANIZATION_ID` where I store information about relationship of organizations.

This code returns all organizations that have a specific ID in the column `TREE_ORGANIZATION_ID`. In my case this code return `Google` and `YouTube` entries.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM 
    ORGANIZATIONS
WHERE 
    TREE_ORGANIZATION_ID LIKE '%\' || '6'
OR
    TREE_ORGANIZATION_ID LIKE '%\' || '6' || '\%';
```

I want to add new column called `STATUS` which looks like this:

```
| ORGANIZATION_ID | ORGANIZATION_NAME | TREE_ORGANIZATION_ID | ORGANIZATION_RANG | STATUS   |
|-----------------|-------------------|----------------------|-------------------|----------|
| 6               | Google            | \4\6                 | 2                 | root     |
| 7               | YouTube           | \4\6\7               | 3                 | not root |
```

I tried next code but it raise error `ORA-00937 not a single-group group function`.

How do I create a new column based on the value of another column?

```
SELECT
    ORGANIZATION_ID,
    ORGANIZATION_NAME,
    TREE_ORGANIZATION_ID,
    CASE
        WHEN ORGANIZATION_RANG = MIN(ORGANIZATION_RANG) THEN 'root'
        ELSE 'not root'
    END AS STATUS
FROM 
    ORGANIZATIONS
WHERE 
    TREE_ORGANIZATION_ID LIKE '%\' || '6'
OR
    TREE_ORGANIZATION_ID LIKE '%\' || '6' || '\%';
```

Comment: ORGANIZATION_RANG = MIN(ORGANIZATION_RANG) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use an analytic function, not an aggregation function:

```
SELECT ORGANIZATION_ID, ORGANIZATION_NAME, TREE_ORGANIZATION_ID,
       (CASE WHEN ORGANIZATION_RANG = MIN(ORGANIZATION_RANG) OVER ()
             THEN 'root'
             ELSE 'not root'
        END) AS STATUS
FROM ORGANIZATIONS O
WHERE TREE_ORGANIZATION_ID || '\' LIKE '%\' || '6' || '\%';
```

Note that this also simplifies the logic for matching `6` by testing the organization id with a backslash on the end.  You could also use `REGEXP_LIKE()` for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

You can try below -

```
SELECT
    ORGANIZATION_ID,
    ORGANIZATION_NAME,
    TREE_ORGANIZATION_ID,
    CASE
        WHEN TREE_ORGANIZATION_ID LIKE '%\' || '6' THEN 'root'
        when TREE_ORGANIZATION_ID LIKE '%\' || '6' || '\%' then 'not root'
    END AS STATUS
FROM 
    ORGANIZATIONS
WHERE 
    TREE_ORGANIZATION_ID LIKE '%\' || '6'
OR
    TREE_ORGANIZATION_ID LIKE '%\' || '6' || '\%'
```